# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0

Tags: java

I just have this error. I have this

```
private List<String> neighbourNames;
```

Which contains the names of the peers in the network. When a peer try to leave the network try to remove itself in the list of the others peer. This happens but in the end I got an error. Here is the code

```
for(String s : neighbourNames){
            try {
                stub = (PeerInterface) registry.lookup(s);
            } catch (NotBoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot reach " + s + ", probably is offline");
            }
            stub.removeMeFromNetwork(nome,key);

        }
```

The error is the one showed in the title and...

```
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.removeMeFromNetwork(Unknown Source)
    at com.server.PeerNode.leaveNetwork(PeerNode.java:181)
    at com.server.PeerNode.printMenu(PeerNode.java:475)
    at com.server.PeerNode.run(PeerNode.java:118)
    at com.server.Main.main(Main.java:85)
```

The line that throw that error is : stub.removeMeFromNetwork(nome,key);

This is the implementation of removeMeFromNetwork:

```
public void removeMeFromNetwork(String nome, int ke) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(nome + " is leaving the network");

        neighbourNames.remove(nome);
        listKey.remove(ke);
        System.out.println("QUALCUNO E' USCITO VICINI RIMANENTI\n"+ neighbourNames);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What line is throwing that error? The error itself is self-explanatory: you are trying to access an index of an array/list that doesn't exist. In this case, the array/list is empty (size: 0).

Comment: Please provide more information about related methods, variables, etc.

Comment: `removeMeFromNetwork(...)` add it's implementation

Comment: I added the implementation, but everything works fine. When the list comes to the end.... the problem comes out

Answer (score 0):

The interface `List` has two `remove` methods, one that accepts an object ([`List.remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)) and one that accepts an index number ([`List.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)). When you have a `List<Integer>` you have to take care to invoke the right one.

I.e., in your code you have a parameter `int ke` and invoke `listKey.remove(ke);` which will invoke `List.remove(int)` and interpret `ke` as index rather than as element. You can remove an `Integer` object by inserting a type cast, `listKey.remove((Integer)ke);`

Comment: thank you soooo much. I couldn't even image to find the error there!!! In that line... thank you!!!